# Wald problem 4 of chapter 4

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, linearized-theory

I'm trying to derive equation 4.4.51 in [Wald's GR](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=9S-hzg6-moYC&lpg=PP1&pg=PP1#v=onepage&q&f=false) book (the second order correction in $\gamma$ term for the [Ricci tensor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ricci_curvature)):

[image]

where $g=\eta+\gamma$. So $g^{\mu\nu}=\eta^{\mu\nu}-\gamma^{\mu\nu}+O(\gamma^2)$.

I'm not sure how to proceed, but I got stuck for quite a while:

Take 
$$\Gamma^{\mu}\,_{\alpha\beta}={}^{\left(1\right)}\Gamma^{\mu}\,_{\alpha\beta}+{}^{\left(2\right)}\Gamma^{\mu}\,_{\alpha\beta}+\mathcal{O}\left(\gamma^{3}\right)$$ 
where 
$${}^{\left(1\right)}\Gamma^{\mu}\,_{\alpha\beta}=+\eta^{\mu\nu}\partial_{(\alpha}\gamma_{\beta)\nu}-\frac{1}{2}\eta^{\mu\nu}\partial_{\nu}\gamma_{\alpha\beta}$$ 
and 
$${}^{\left(2\right)}\Gamma^{\mu}\,_{\alpha\beta}=-\gamma^{\mu\nu}\partial_{(\alpha}\gamma_{\beta)\nu}+\frac{1}{2}\gamma^{\mu\nu}\partial_{\nu}\gamma_{\alpha\beta}.$$
Writing
\begin{align}
R_{\mu\rho}  = & \partial_{\nu}\Gamma^{\nu}\,_{\mu\rho}-\partial_{\mu}\Gamma^{\nu}\,_{\nu\rho}+2\Gamma^{\alpha}\,_{\rho[\mu}\Gamma^{\nu}\,_{\nu]\alpha}\\
  = & \underbrace{\partial_{\nu}\,^{\left(1\right)}\Gamma^{\nu}\,_{\mu\rho}-\partial_{\mu}\,^{\left(1\right)}\Gamma^{\nu}\,_{\nu\rho}}_{^{\left(1\right)}R_{\mu\rho}}\\
   & +\underbrace{\partial_{\nu}\,^{\left(2\right)}\Gamma^{\nu}\,_{\mu\rho}-\partial_{\mu}\,^{\left(2\right)}\Gamma^{\nu}\,_{\nu\rho}+2\,^{\left(1\right)}\Gamma^{\alpha}\,_{\rho[\mu}\,^{\left(1\right)}\Gamma^{\nu}\,_{\nu]\alpha}}_{^{\left(2\right)}R_{\mu\rho}}\\
   & +\mathcal{O}\left(\gamma^{3}\right)
\end{align}

This is what I have so far:
[my attempt](https://www.sharelatex.com/project/5392214c43a7a5634e5720a7?r=7ca8ae6c&rs=ps&rm=d)

\begin{align}
{}^{\left(2\right)}R_{\mu\rho} = & \partial_{\nu}\,^{\left(2\right)}\Gamma^{\nu}\,_{\mu\rho}-\partial_{\mu}\,^{\left(2\right)}\Gamma^{\nu}\,_{\nu\rho}+\,^{\left(1\right)}\Gamma^{\alpha}\,_{\mu\rho}\,^{\left(1\right)}\Gamma^{\nu}\,_{\alpha\nu}-\,^{\left(1\right)}\Gamma^{\alpha}\,_{\nu\rho}\,^{\left(1\right)}\Gamma^{\nu}\,_{\alpha\mu}\\
  = & \partial_{\nu}\left(-\gamma^{\nu\lambda}\partial_{(\mu}\gamma_{\rho)\lambda}+\frac{1}{2}\gamma^{\nu\lambda}\partial_{\lambda}\gamma_{\mu\rho}\right)\\
   & -\partial_{\mu}\left(-\gamma^{\nu\lambda}\partial_{(\nu}\gamma_{\rho)\lambda}+\frac{1}{2}\gamma^{\nu\lambda}\partial_{\lambda}\gamma_{\nu\rho}\right)\\
   & +\,^{\left(1\right)}\Gamma^{\alpha}\,_{\mu\rho}\,^{\left(1\right)}\Gamma^{\nu}\,_{\alpha\nu}\\
   & -\,^{\left(1\right)}\Gamma^{\alpha}\,_{\nu\rho}\,^{\left(1\right)}\Gamma^{\nu}\,_{\alpha\mu}\\
  = & \gamma^{\nu\lambda}\left(-\partial_{\nu}\partial_{(\mu}\gamma_{\rho)\lambda}+\frac{1}{2}\partial_{\nu}\partial_{\lambda}\gamma_{\mu\rho}+\partial_{\mu}\partial_{(\nu}\gamma_{\rho)\lambda}-\frac{1}{2}\partial_{\mu}\partial_{\lambda}\gamma_{\nu\rho}\right)\\
   & +\eta^{\alpha\beta}\left(\partial_{(\mu}\gamma_{\rho)\beta}-\frac{1}{2}\partial_{\beta}\gamma_{\mu\rho}\right)\eta^{\nu\lambda}\left(\partial_{(\alpha}\gamma_{\nu)\lambda}-\frac{1}{2}\partial_{\lambda}\gamma_{\alpha\nu}\right)\\
   & -\eta^{\alpha\beta}\left(\partial_{(\nu}\gamma_{\rho)\beta}-\frac{1}{2}\partial_{\beta}\gamma_{\nu\rho}\right)\eta^{\nu\lambda}\left(\partial_{(\alpha}\gamma_{\mu)\lambda}-\frac{1}{2}\partial_{\lambda}\gamma_{\alpha\mu}\right)\\
  = & \frac{1}{2}\gamma^{\nu\lambda}\partial_{\mu}\partial_{\rho}\gamma_{\nu\lambda}-\gamma^{\nu\lambda}\partial_{\nu}\partial_{(\rho}\gamma_{\mu)\lambda}+\frac{1}{2}\gamma^{\nu\lambda}\partial_{\nu}\partial_{\lambda}\gamma_{\mu\rho}\\
   & +\frac{1}{4}\eta^{\alpha\beta}\left(\partial_{\mu}\gamma_{\rho\beta}+\partial_{\rho}\gamma_{\mu\beta}-\partial_{\beta}\gamma_{\mu\rho}\right)\partial_{\alpha}\gamma\\
   & -\frac{1}{4}\eta^{\alpha\beta}\eta^{\nu\lambda}\left(\partial_{\nu}\gamma_{\rho\beta}+\partial_{\rho}\gamma_{\nu\beta}-\partial_{\beta}\gamma_{\nu\rho}\right)\left(\partial_{\alpha}\gamma_{\mu\lambda}+\partial_{\mu}\gamma_{\alpha\lambda}-\partial_{\lambda}\gamma_{\alpha\mu}\right)\\
  = & \frac{1}{2}\gamma^{\nu\lambda}\partial_{\mu}\partial_{\rho}\gamma_{\nu\lambda}-\gamma^{\nu\lambda}\partial_{\nu}\partial_{(\rho}\gamma_{\mu)\lambda}+\frac{1}{2}\partial_{\nu}\left(\frac{1}{2}\gamma^{\nu\lambda}\partial_{\lambda}\gamma_{\mu\rho}\right)-\frac{1}{2}\partial_{\nu}\gamma^{\nu\lambda}\partial_{\lambda}\gamma_{\mu\rho}\\
   & +\frac{1}{4}\eta^{\alpha\beta}\eta^{\nu\lambda}(\\
   & \partial_{\mu}\gamma_{\rho\beta}\partial_{\alpha}\gamma+\partial_{\rho}\gamma_{\mu\beta}\partial_{\alpha}\gamma-\partial_{\beta}\gamma_{\mu\rho}\partial_{\alpha}\gamma\\
   & -\partial_{\nu}\gamma_{\rho\beta}\partial_{\alpha}\gamma_{\mu\lambda}-\partial_{\nu}\gamma_{\rho\beta}\partial_{\mu}\gamma_{\alpha\lambda}+\partial_{\nu}\gamma_{\rho\beta}\partial_{\lambda}\gamma_{\alpha\mu}-\partial_{\rho}\gamma_{\nu\beta}\partial_{\alpha}\gamma_{\mu\lambda}-\partial_{\rho}\gamma_{\nu\beta}\partial_{\mu}\gamma_{\alpha\lambda}\\
   & +\partial_{\rho}\gamma_{\nu\beta}\partial_{\lambda}\gamma_{\alpha\mu}+\partial_{\beta}\gamma_{\nu\rho}\partial_{\alpha}\gamma_{\mu\lambda}+\partial_{\beta}\gamma_{\nu\rho}\partial_{\mu}\gamma_{\alpha\lambda}-\partial_{\beta}\gamma_{\nu\rho}\partial_{\lambda}\gamma_{\alpha\mu})\\
  = & \frac{1}{2}\gamma^{\nu\lambda}\partial_{\mu}\partial_{\rho}\gamma_{\nu\lambda}-\gamma^{\nu\lambda}\partial_{\nu}\partial_{(\rho}\gamma_{\mu)\lambda}+\frac{1}{2}\partial_{\nu}\left(\frac{1}{2}\gamma^{\nu\lambda}\partial_{\lambda}\gamma_{\mu\rho}\right)-\frac{1}{2}\partial_{\nu}\gamma^{\nu\lambda}\partial_{\lambda}\gamma_{\mu\rho}\\
   & +\frac{1}{4}\eta^{\alpha\beta}\eta^{\nu\lambda}(2\partial_{(\mu}\gamma_{\rho)\beta}\partial_{\alpha}\gamma-\partial_{\beta}\gamma_{\mu\rho}\partial_{\alpha}\gamma\\
   & -\partial_{\nu}\gamma_{\rho\beta}\partial_{\alpha}\gamma_{\mu\lambda}-\partial_{\nu}\gamma_{\rho\beta}\partial_{\mu}\gamma_{\alpha\lambda}+\partial_{\nu}\gamma_{\rho\beta}\partial_{\lambda}\gamma_{\alpha\mu}-\partial_{\rho}\gamma_{\nu\beta}\partial_{\alpha}\gamma_{\mu\lambda}-\partial_{\rho}\gamma_{\nu\beta}\partial_{\mu}\gamma_{\alpha\lambda}\\
   & +\partial_{\rho}\gamma_{\nu\beta}\partial_{\lambda}\gamma_{\alpha\mu}+\partial_{\beta}\gamma_{\nu\rho}\partial_{\alpha}\gamma_{\mu\lambda}+\partial_{\beta}\gamma_{\nu\rho}\partial_{\mu}\gamma_{\alpha\lambda}-\partial_{\beta}\gamma_{\nu\rho}\partial_{\lambda}\gamma_{\alpha\mu})
\end{align}

In my last line, somehow it seems like too many terms cancel out to get what the book has, in particular, there aren't enough $\gamma_{\mu\rho}$ terms..

Comment: Please, try to include the relevant equations in your answer. It's annoying to go through a link.